# Why does the global $_SERVER array take 13x the memory?

Tags: php, memory-management, global-variables

When creating an new array (and element) using plain PHP arrays the following code uses 360 bytes in PHP 5.3 with and without APC. Even adding an element to $_GET only uses 304 bytes. However, when creating an additional element in $_SERVER the same code uses 4,896 bytes!

```
$mem = memory_get_usage();

//$array = array('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' => NULL);
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] = NULL;
//$_GET['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] = NULL;

print (memory_get_usage() - $mem).' bytes<br>';
print memory_get_usage().' bytes (process)<br>';
print memory_get_peak_usage(TRUE). ' bytes (process peak)<br>';
print (memory_get_usage() - $mem).' bytes<br>';
```

What in the world causes the $_SERVER array to use so much extra memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike's explanation of how PHP dynamically allocates the internal hash table for arrays is spot on. The doubling of size is very performant for dynamically allocating arrays.

However, the $_SERVER, $_REQUEST, $_POST, $_GET, and $_ENV superglobals are all of a fixed size when the script starts. They are also generally not edited (I discourage it).

It's very likely that they are created with hash tables that are just big enough to fit their current size. Any addition would then trigger the dynamic expansion algorithm to rebuild and copy to the hash table.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't worry about low level details like that if I were developing on PHP. What's probably happening is that you've hit a capacity limit on $_SERVER, and PHP has to create a new hash table that is double the size of the current hash table. Since these are ordered associated arrays, there is a fairly large overhead cost to each element of the hash table, even spots that are not filled.

If you are interested in the mechanics of this process, they are available in [zend_hash.c](http://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/Zend/zend_hash.c), line 418.

To test this, take a var_dump of your $_SERVER then put it in the script. Please be sure to not just test a dummy hash table for a couple reasons: (1) there are actually different C code paths for php "dynamic arrays" versus php "hash tables" (it converts them for you), and (2) the issue may be with copying so many strings over to the new hash table to avoid thread safety or the pointer overhead.

Comment: 5kb of overhead in random places for NULL values is certainly something to watch out for. However, if the hash table is the answer perhaps I can duplicate the problem by filling up a plain PHP array and watching memory usage.

Comment: Yeah, I would first dump the contents of $_SERVER and test with your own copy first.

Comment: Ok, I just slowly created an array and at 8, 16, 32, 64 etc.. the array shows larger memory jumps of 128, 160, 224, & 352 bytes. However, this doesn't add up because my server array only has 70 items in it (well before the next jump of 128 items) yet it jumps by over 4kb for just one more `NULL` item.

Comment: @Xeoncross, these are low probability occurrences.. and 5kb is not too high a cost to pay for not having to worry about the low level details of how everything works.

Comment: @Xeoncross: While possible, the $_SERVER, $_GET, $_POST, and $_REQUEST superglobals are really not intended to be edited. It's possible yours is created with precisely 70 "items" in them, your sole addition could be triggering a rebuild to the new size.

Comment: @Mike: You shouldn't infer that he is "worrying" about anything. It could just be scholarly curiosity; I know I'm curious.

Comment: @hobodave I think your on to something. I tried adding directly to the $_SERVER array and found that after the first element was added taking an extra 5kb - each additional element (to 128 elements) was only 96 bytes. The 128 element cost 608 bytes as the array was rebuilt.

Comment: @hobodave: I think you should post that as an answer. :)